# Suppose A is a square matrix that satisfies the matrix equation $A^5 = A$. Find, with justification, all possible eigenvalues of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

From what I understand, because any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of A will solve the equation 
$$
\lambda^5=\lambda\\
0=(A^5−A)v=(\lambda^5−λ)v
$$
Is this a sufficient answer? It seems lame to just say that any possible eigenvalue of A is the answer..

Comment: You've left out important context.  What kind of matrix is $A$?  See [this introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: All thats given in the question is that it is a square matrix. No other information is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, assuming $v$ is an eigenvector, you have $v \ne \vec{0}$, thus you must have 
$$
0 = \lambda^5 - \lambda = \lambda\left(\lambda^4 - 1\right)
  = \lambda\left(\lambda^2 - 1\right)\left(\lambda^2 + 1\right),
$$
which easily factorizes further... Can you finish this?

Comment: so setting λ(λ^2−1)(λ^2+1)=0 we could solve for lambda = 0, or +/- 1?

Comment: @shroomyshroomy:  there are two more roots than that.  They are complex, but that is no problem.  I am sure you are expected to find them as well.

Comment: thats where you lose me.. I can factor to ) but im unsure what other complex roots one could find λ(λ−1)(λ+1)(λ^2+1)=0

Comment: Though technically, for a complete solution to the question as asked, once you find the possible values of $\lambda$ you would need to verify each of them is actually possible so you know you didn't find any extraneous solutions.

Comment: Is there a way to verify with just the information given? This practice problem is from an old exam that weights it as 4/100 exam total points for reference. Most questions worth ~10-15 marks each. Seems like it should be a quick little answer type q

Comment: For a $4-$point question, I'm sure you would just be expected to answer $0, \pm 1, \pm i$